# Moving logic from controller to service

Tags: grails

I have just started moving logic from my controllers to services in my Grails project. 
One of the things I need to do is list the `Teams` that a `Member` can join. 
The member has a list of `Registration` objects, that belongTo a Team and a Member, linking them together. 
In the controller, I was able to remove the get a Team-list and remove the Teams that the member was already registered to, by doing this.

```
def teamsPossible = Team.list()

member.registrations.each { reg ->
    teamsPossible.remove(reg.team)
}
```

Now that I have moved the code to a service instead, Teams can no longer be removed from the list in this way.

From the service I have tried printing the full list of teams in `teamsPossible` and the `reg.team`s to be removed. They are indeed all there, they are just not removed... So it is not a question of accessing the same data as in the controller...

Comment: Moving the above code from controller to service can not make it stop working. So when you say its not working, what is happening ? Also remember, services are transnational by default, so make sure your transaction is not getting rolled back because of some error etc. You can enable logSql in datasource and verify the update / delete queries are actually being fired

Comment: Sorry. By not working I mean, that even though the Team in reg.team is in the list teamsPossible, it is not removed.. 
I am also not using the database, so @transactional shouldn't be an issue, should it?

Comment: By default it used the h2 database and support transactions

Comment: Ok, I have found a workaround... 

If I leave a line just saying "Team.list()" in the controller - ie. not using the data at all, just making a request to the database - the whole thing acts as it should... I cannot figure out why, but it does work...

Comment: It's because it is flushing your transaction!